# jQuery drag and drop between select elements?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible, using jQuery, to drag option elements from one `select` to another?

Comment: Please refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452866/jquery-drag-and-drop-elements-from-list-into-separate-blocks

Comment: @Umesh: that question doesn't seem particularly relevant to this one; and in this question: the answer, I think, is 'no.' Since the `option` elements don't seem to be draggable (though admittedly, that's from memory, and perhaps a much earlier version of jQuery).

Comment: I dummied up a test and the options still don't seem to be draggable.

Comment: @DavidThomas, thank you for pointing that out.but it would be uneasy for end-users to drag and drop from selectboxes than lists. Hence my pointer.