# Copy an item and drop into other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Below code is my script written for drag and drop. but i need to copy the list item and drop to other location.

now i am able to drag and drop into other divs, but i am unable to copy or clone the list item and need to place in other divs.

Can you please help for this solution .I tried a lot to find the solution.as i am less experience in JavaScript i am unable to find.I am very thankful if you give the solution for me .

```
(function()
{
    if
    (
        !document.querySelectorAll 
        || 
        !('draggable' in document.createElement('span')) 
        || 
        window.opera
    ) 
    { return; }

    //get the collection of draggable targets and add their draggable attribute
    for(var 
        targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="target"]'), 
        len = targets.length, 
        i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    {
        targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'none');
    }

    //get the collection of draggable items and add their draggable attributes
    for(var 
        items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="item"]'), 
        len = items.length, 
        i = 0; i < len; i ++)
    {
        items[i].setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
        items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
    }



    //dictionary for storing the selections data 
    //comprising an array of the currently selected items 
    //a reference to the selected items' owning container
    //and a refernce to the current drop target container
    var selections = 
    {
        items      : [],
        owner      : null,
        droptarget : null
    };

    //function for selecting an item
    function addSelection(item)
    {
        //if the owner reference is still null, set it to this item's parent
        //so that further selection is only allowed within the same container
        if(!selections.owner)
        {
            selections.owner = item.parentNode;
        }

        //or if that's already happened then compare it with this item's parent
        //and if they're not the same container, return to prevent selection
        else if(selections.owner != item.parentNode)
        {
            return;
        }

        //set this item's grabbed state
        item.setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'true');

        //add it to the items array
        selections.items.push(item);
    }

    //function for unselecting an item
    function removeSelection(item)
    {
        //reset this item's grabbed state





        item.setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');

        //then find and remove this item from the existing items array
        for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        {
            if(selections.items[i] == item)
            {
                selections.items.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //function for resetting all selections
    function clearSelections()
    {
        //if we have any selected items
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            //reset the owner reference
            selections.owner = null;

            //reset the grabbed state on every selected item
            for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                selections.items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
            }

            //then reset the items array        
            selections.items = [];
        }
    }

    //shorctut function for testing whether a selection modifier is pressed
    function hasModifier(e)
    {
        return (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey);
    }


    //function for applying dropeffect to the target containers
    function addDropeffects()
    {
        //apply aria-dropeffect and tabindex to all targets apart from the owner
        for(var len = targets.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        {
            if
            (
                targets[i] != selections.owner 
                && 
                targets[i].getAttribute('aria-dropeffect') == 'none'
            )
            {
                targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'move');
                targets[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
            }
        }

        //remove aria-grabbed and tabindex from all items inside those containers
        for(var len = items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
        {
            if
            (
                items[i].parentNode != selections.owner 
                && 
                items[i].getAttribute('aria-grabbed')
            )
            {
                items[i].removeAttribute('aria-grabbed');
                items[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');
            }
        }        
    }

    //function for removing dropeffect from the target containers
    function clearDropeffects()
    {
        //if we have any selected items
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            //reset aria-dropeffect and remove tabindex from all targets
            for(var len = targets.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                if(targets[i].getAttribute('aria-dropeffect') != 'none')
                {
                    targets[i].setAttribute('aria-dropeffect', 'none');
                    targets[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');
                }
            }

            //restore aria-grabbed and tabindex to all selectable items 
            //without changing the grabbed value of any existing selected items
            for(var len = items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                if(!items[i].getAttribute('aria-grabbed'))
                {
                    items[i].setAttribute('aria-grabbed', 'false');
                    items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
                }
                else if(items[i].getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'true')
                {
                    items[i].setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
                }
            }        
        }
    }

    //shortcut function for identifying an event element's target container
    function getContainer(element)
    {
        do
        {
            if(element.nodeType == 1 && element.getAttribute('aria-dropeffect'))
            {
                return element;
            }
        }
        while(element = element.parentNode);

        return null;
    }



    //mousedown event to implement single selection
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a draggable item
        if(e.target.getAttribute('draggable'))
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();

            //if the multiple selection modifier is not pressed 
            //and the item's grabbed state is currently false
            if
            (
                !hasModifier(e) 
                && 
                e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'false'
            )
            {
                //clear all existing selections
                clearSelections();

                //then add this new selection
                addSelection(e.target);
            }
        }

        //else [if the element is anything else]
        //and the selection modifier is not pressed 
        else if(!hasModifier(e))
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();

            //clear all existing selections
            clearSelections();
        }

        //else [if the element is anything else and the modifier is pressed]
        else
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();
        }

    }, false);

    //mouseup event to implement multiple selection
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a draggable item 
        //and the multipler selection modifier is pressed
        if(e.target.getAttribute('draggable') && hasModifier(e))
        {
            //if the item's grabbed state is currently true
            if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'true')
            {
                //unselect this item
                removeSelection(e.target);

                //if that was the only selected item
                //then reset the owner container reference
                if(!selections.items.length)
                {
                    selections.owner = null;
                }
            }

            //else [if the item's grabbed state is false]
            else
            {
                //add this additional selection
                addSelection(e.target);
            }
        }

    }, false);

    //dragstart event to initiate mouse dragging
    document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e)
    {
        //if the element's parent is not the owner, then block this event
        if(selections.owner != e.target.parentNode)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        //[else] if the multiple selection modifier is pressed 
        //and the item's grabbed state is currently false
        if
        (
            hasModifier(e) 
            && 
            e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'false'
        )
        {
            //add this additional selection
            addSelection(e.target);
        }

        //we don't need the transfer data, but we have to define something
        //otherwise the drop action won't work at all in firefox
        //most browsers support the proper mime-type syntax, eg. "text/plain"
        //but we have to use this incorrect syntax for the benefit of IE10+
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', '');

        //apply dropeffect to the target containers
        addDropeffects();

    }, false);



    //keydown event to implement selection and abort
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a grabbable item 
        if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed'))
        {
            //Space is the selection or unselection keystroke
            if(e.keyCode == 32)
            {
                //if the multiple selection modifier is pressed 
                if(hasModifier(e))
                {
                    //if the item's grabbed state is currently true
                    if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'true')
                    {
                        //if this is the only selected item, clear dropeffect 
                        //from the target containers, which we must do first
                        //in case subsequent unselection sets owner to null
                        if(selections.items.length == 1)
                        {
                            clearDropeffects();
                        }

                        //unselect this item
                        removeSelection(e.target);

                        //if we have any selections
                        //apply dropeffect to the target containers, 
                        //in case earlier selections were made by mouse
                        if(selections.items.length)
                        {
                            addDropeffects();
                        }

                        //if that was the only selected item
                        //then reset the owner container reference
                        if(!selections.items.length)
                        {
                            selections.owner = null;
                        }
                    }

                    //else [if its grabbed state is currently false]
                    else
                    {
                        //add this additional selection
                        addSelection(e.target);

                        //apply dropeffect to the target containers    
                        addDropeffects();
                    }
                }

                //else [if the multiple selection modifier is not pressed]
                //and the item's grabbed state is currently false
                else if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-grabbed') == 'false')
                {
                    //clear dropeffect from the target containers
                    clearDropeffects();

                    //clear all existing selections
                    clearSelections();

                    //add this new selection
                    addSelection(e.target);

                    //apply dropeffect to the target containers
                    addDropeffects();
                }

                //else [if modifier is not pressed and grabbed is already true]
                else
                {
                    //apply dropeffect to the target containers    
                    addDropeffects();
                }

                //then prevent default to avoid any conflict with native actions
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            //Modifier + M is the end-of-selection keystroke
            if(e.keyCode == 77 && hasModifier(e))
            {
                //if we have any selected items
                if(selections.items.length)
                {
                    //apply dropeffect to the target containers    
                    //in case earlier selections were made by mouse
                    addDropeffects();

                    //if the owner container is the last one, focus the first one
                    if(selections.owner == targets[targets.length - 1])
                    {
                        targets[0].focus();
                    }

                    //else [if it's not the last one], find and focus the next one
                    else
                    {
                        for(var len = targets.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
                        {
                            if(selections.owner == targets[i])
                            {
                                targets[i + 1].focus();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                

                //then prevent default to avoid any conflict with native actions
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        //Escape is the abort keystroke (for any target element)
        if(e.keyCode == 27)
        {
            //if we have any selected items
            if(selections.items.length)
            {
                //clear dropeffect from the target containers
                clearDropeffects();

                //then set focus back on the last item that was selected, which is 
                //necessary because we've removed tabindex from the current focus
                selections.items[selections.items.length - 1].focus();

                //clear all existing selections
                clearSelections();

                //but don't prevent default so that native actions can still occur
            }
        }

    }, false);



    //related variable is needed to maintain a reference to the 
    //dragleave's relatedTarget, since it doesn't have e.relatedTarget
    var related = null;

    //dragenter event to set that variable
    document.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e)
    {
        related = e.target;

    }, false);

    //dragleave event to maintain target highlighting using that variable
    document.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e)
    {
        //get a drop target reference from the relatedTarget
        var droptarget = getContainer(related);

        //if the target is the owner then it's not a valid drop target
        if(droptarget == selections.owner)
        {
            droptarget = null;
        }

        //if the drop target is different from the last stored reference
        //(or we have one of those references but not the other one)
        if(droptarget != selections.droptarget)
        {
            //if we have a saved reference, clear its existing dragover class
            if(selections.droptarget)
            {
                selections.droptarget.className = 
                    selections.droptarget.className.replace(/ dragover/g, '');
            }

            //apply the dragover class to the new drop target reference
            if(droptarget)
            {
                droptarget.className += ' dragover';
            }

            //then save that reference for next time
            selections.droptarget = droptarget;
        }

    }, false);    

    //dragover event to allow the drag by preventing its default
    document.addEventListener('dragover', function(e)
    {
        //if we have any selected items, allow them to be dragged
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }, false);    



    //dragend event to implement items being validly dropped into targets,
    //or invalidly dropped elsewhere, and to clean-up the interface either way
    document.addEventListener('dragend', function(e)
    {
        //if we have a valid drop target reference
        //(which implies that we have some selected items)
        if(selections.droptarget)
        {
            //append the selected items to the end of the target container
            for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
            {
                selections.droptarget.appendChild(selections.items[i]);
            }

            //prevent default to allow the action            
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        //if we have any selected items
        if(selections.items.length)
        {
            //clear dropeffect from the target containers
            clearDropeffects();

            //if we have a valid drop target reference
            if(selections.droptarget)
            {
                //reset the selections array
                clearSelections();

                //reset the target's dragover class
                selections.droptarget.className = 
                    selections.droptarget.className.replace(/ dragover/g, '');

                //reset the target reference
                selections.droptarget = null;
            }
        }

    }, false);



    //keydown event to implement items being dropped into targets
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
    {
        //if the element is a drop target container
        if(e.target.getAttribute('aria-dropeffect'))
        {
            //Enter or Modifier + M is the drop keystroke
            if(e.keyCode == 13 || (e.keyCode == 77 && hasModifier(e)))
            {
                //append the selected items to the end of the target container
                for(var len = selections.items.length, i = 0; i < len; i ++)
                {
                    e.target.appendChild(selections.items[i]);
                }

                //clear dropeffect from the target containers
                clearDropeffects();

                //then set focus back on the last item that was selected, which is 
                //necessary because we've removed tabindex from the current focus
                selections.items[selections.items.length - 1].focus();

                //reset the selections array
                clearSelections();

                //prevent default to to avoid any conflict with native actions
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    }, false);

  })();
```

**HTML Code :**

these are dives which i am placing from list item to other divs.I need to copy the li item from mrbr class div and need to drop into GPAnd_Block and other divs.The below are html classes

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="mbrdr">
    <ol>
      <li class="selectActionItem" data-draggable="item">History of present illness <a class="removeActionItem" data-itemid="2">remove</a></li>
      <li class="selectActionItem" data-draggable="item">chief complaint <a class="removeActionItem" data-itemid="2">remove</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h4 class="pull-left">Good Path Actions</h4>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="GPOrBlock">
    <ol data-draggable="target"  class="ol_style">
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 GPAnd_Block">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="radio" name="GPAnd_Radio" value="AG_1" />
        <a class="removeActionGroup pull-right">X</a>
    </div>
    <ol data-draggable="target" id="AG_1" class="ol_style">
    </ol>
  </div>
```

[This is screen looks like.the list are shown in the left side .that need to copy and drop to right side divs.Present drag and drop the item is removing from left side div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdfjW.png)

Comment: Why not just use jQuery UI? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452866/jquery-drag-and-drop-elements-from-list-into-separate-blocks

Comment: titles cannot start with `i need`. describe the problem itself