# Jquery draggable / sortable tool bar icons dropped onto page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I don't know if anyone is able to help with this, but what i need to achieve is this.

To have a vertical menu on the right hand side of the page in a div / div(s), and vertically stacked would be different icons eventually.  What I need to do and cant seem to locate the correct reference, is to select one of the icons in the right hand side vertical menu, and drag it onto the page on the left and drop it in a constrained area.

This is to give me the start of a basic page builder, so an icon clicked and dragged would still stay in the vertical right hand side menu, but i guess a copy would appear to be dragged onto the left.

What I need to know then is a) which icon was selected and dragged and b) where it was dropped.

Is this something jquery draggable/sortable would be able to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site Adrian! Please, take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Also, have you taken a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452866/jquery-drag-and-drop-elements-from-list-into-separate-blocks Is it of any help?

Comment: Hi, yes thanks that seems to be along the right lines.  I presume I would have to then have the items to drag into on the left of my page?